# Video not playing in html (webhost000 or byethost5)

Tags: html, video, web-hosting

I'm writing because I made a background video for my site, of course its looks like this:

```
  <video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth fadeIn wow collapse in" data-wow-delay="0.5s" poster="images/poster.jpg" id="video-background">
        <source src="video/wd0280.webm" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
```

And my problem is that it normally plays in localhost, but when I go to a hosting site, for example webhost000 or byethost then its stop playing, even if I try with different video format
Why is this happening? Is it in connection with the free webhosting servers? Can someone tell me then which to choose to work perfectly?
Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe to play any media file at webpage

```
<iframe width="440" height="350"
src="http://www.cricingif.com/Ball/201004">
</iframe>
Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
```

Comment: It's not working, it gives me the homepage of the webhost000, also as I said its a background video (not a little box)

Comment: you can change width and height of the frame.

Comment: i edited my post and paste another webpage link. and its working fine.

Comment: Maybe I should uload my video on a server, and link it... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I misstyped my video file name, so it was a typo, but now its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the video is muted for it to play in a modern browser. Try:

```
<video autoplay muted loop= class="fillWidth fadeIn wow collapse in"
    data-wow-delay="0.5s" poster="images/poster.jpg" id="video-background">
  <source src="video/wd0280.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```